# PHP: Fatal error: Call to undefined method case_controller

Tags: php, methods, undefined, require, fatal-error

I have difficulties trying to call a function even though i have already used "require_once". I'm not sure if the $caseCtrl is even being defined, which could explain the reason why I can't use retrieveAllCaseID() (in create_case.php file).

Here's the flow: create_case.php (user interface/form) -> case_controller.php -> caseDAO.php

**This is my error:**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method case_controller::retrieveAllCaseID() in \dct\view\create_case.php on line 82
```

**create_case.php file:**

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '\..\controller\case_controller.php');
$caseCtrl = new case_controller();
$caseCtrl->retrieveAllCaseID(); //this line is calling the error
```

**case_cotroller.php file:**

```
function retrieveAllCaseID() {
$caseDAO = new caseDAO();
$result_array = $caseDAO->retrieveAllCaseID();

return $result_array;
}
```

**caseDAO.php file:**

```
function retrieveAllCaseID() {
$allCaseID = Array();

$dbMgr = new dbManager();
$conn = $dbMgr->getDBConnection();

// peform query
$query = "select case_id from case_report where case_status like '%Follow Up%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) 
{
  print "<br />";
  die ('(caseDAO.php->retrieveAllCaseID)Error in executing query: '.mysql_error());
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
  return null;
}

while ($resultSet = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $allCaseID[]= $resultSet['case_id'];
}

$dbMgr->closeDBConnection($conn);

return $allCaseID;

}//retrieveAllCaseID
```

I'm aware that there are similar cases here, but I can't seem to find one that really 'answers' my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if create_case.php file you create an object of case_controller and want to run the method retrieveAllCaseID but in case_controller.php file you have only a declaration of the function, not the class and method.

If you change your create_case.php file into:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '\..\controller\case_controller.php');
$caseCtrl = retrieveAllCaseID(); //this line is calling the error
```

there wouldn't be this error. However, they might occur other errors because we don't know what you wanted to do in your application.

I also assume in this answer that there is a typo in "case_cotroller.php file:" - because it should be "case_controller.php file:"

Comment: It's working now, thanks so much! Yea, I had a typo there, but not in the actual file. May I know the difference between -> and =?. Sorry I'm new to php

Comment: When you use -> it means you run method of object or display property of object. When you use = you simple assign result from the right to the left